# Inner div scrollable with max height

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the following markup:

I want inner div to be scrollable and with max height, but I dont want div height to expand more than the height of the content, if height of the content is smaller. Check fiddle and resize the height to see the effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/dapv7bor/1/

```css
.umg-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 80%;
  background: #1a1a1b;
  z-index: 50;
}

.umg-info-data {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.umg-player-title {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.umg-player-desc {
  color: #bbb;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="umg-info">

  <div class="umg-info-data">
    <div class="umg-player-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="umg-player-desc">Praesent molestie. Nunc Venenatis Sapien Ultrices Dui. Vivamus dolor. Integer vel ante. Proin felis. Maecenas non nisl eu mi hendrerit fringilla. Nullam vel ante et nunc accumsan viverra. Vestibulum nulla justo, tristique nec, tincidunt eget, ultricies
      sollicitudin, nulla. Proin dui ante, consectetur a, tincidunt in, mattis ut, ipsum. Sed tristique. Mauris et sapien. Quisque risus. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi. Nam vestibulum viverra diam. Nullam eros ipsum, rutrum ut, ultricies sed, congue sed, est.
      Pellentesque porttitor. Donec dictum urna eu mi. Maecenas in lorem. Vestibulum in ipsum. Praesent ac nunc. Donec vitae lectus. Etiam commodo velit ut mi. Duis egestas, quam faucibus interdum tincidunt, enim sem tincidunt tellus, sed condimentum
      tellus tortor ut mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce aliquet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also relay on the `flex` layout and use `max-height`/`width` to trigger a scrollbar.

example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.umg-info {
  /* because you used it, can be avoided if not for a modal */
  position: absolute;
  /* make a flex box with window's size where content is centered */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.umg-info-data {
  /* single flex child centered, set max-size and overflow */
  max-width: 80vw;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: auto;
  /* makup */
  background: #1a1a1b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #1a1a1b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.umg-player-title {}

.umg-player-desc {}
```

```html
<div class="umg-info">
  <div class="umg-info-data">
  <!-- maybe hx and p tags for text is to be used ? -->
    <h2 class="umg-player-title">Click also 'FULL PAGE'</h2>
    <p class="umg-player-desc">Praesent molestie. Nunc Venenatis Sapien Ultrices Dui. Vivamus dolor. Integer vel ante. Proin felis. Maecenas non nisl eu mi hendrerit fringilla. Nullam vel ante et nunc accumsan viverra. Vestibulum nulla justo, tristique nec, tincidunt eget, ultricies
      sollicitudin, nulla. Proin dui ante, consectetur a, tincidunt in, mattis ut, ipsum. Sed tristique. Mauris et sapien. Quisque risus. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi. Nam vestibulum viverra diam. Nullam eros ipsum, rutrum ut, ultricies sed, congue sed, est.
      Pellentesque porttitor. Donec dictum urna eu mi. Maecenas in lorem. Vestibulum in ipsum. Praesent ac nunc. Donec vitae lectus. Etiam commodo velit ut mi. Duis egestas, quam faucibus interdum tincidunt, enim sem tincidunt tellus, sed condimentum
      tellus tortor ut mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce aliquet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I turn some divs into hx/p tags and set white colors where dark background is set to make sure no children holding text are forgotten. ;)

[codepen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pZpOKz)

Comment: @Toniq Do you mean you cannot ? because else you can indeed use them instead % and it will stick exactly to the viewports height/width ... if the browser understands flex, it understands the viewports unit (vw, vh, vmin and vmax) see https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/  This is as much usefull and easier to use than grid or flex ;) (do not forget to mind the box-model https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ as for any size units used)

Comment: @Toniq any feedback is nice,  just to tells us that our free help on our free time was appreciated a way or an another ....

Answer (score 0):

use scroll on .umg-info & remove height from .umg-info-data

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited to make fiddle working with his example and make more clear what needs to be done

I believe all you should need to do is set`.umg-info-desc {max-height: 90%; overflow: auto;}` (and remove rules from your ata rule). You can see an example of that working at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dapv7bor/14/

Comment: This works as before (I dont see a difference). I dont want black background higher than text (if there is no enough text as in example.)